# How to use “to store them” amounts of paper correctly in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, word-order

This seems off to me and I am not sure how to correct it or if the pronoun is wrong for paper in this sentence:

> You moved a large amount of paper from a space and intended to store them in a room that you are solely using.

Does it need to be more than one sentence, or rearranged for clarity? Could this mean one moved them or it is them??

Answer (score 4):

Choose between...

> 1: *You moved a large <strike>amount</strike> number of **papers** from [somewhere], intending to store **them** [somewhere else]*

> 2: *You moved a large amount of **paper** from [somewhere], intending to store **it** [somewhere else]*

...where #1 emphasises ***many documents*** ("articles", quantified by ***number***), and #2 emphasises ***much paper*** (a "substance", quantified by ***volume***).

Note that although I replaced ***amount*** by ***number*** in #1, that doesn't imply ***amount*** is "incorrect". It's just less common in that exact context. There are several more "non-idiomatic" aspects to the OP's original text, but that's all Off Topic proofreading.

Comment: To me, "papers" implies that the sheets have something written on them with the further connotation that the writing is of a personal or official nature.  "Paper" implies that the sheets are blank or less-commonly with the connotation that any writing that may be on the sheets is of no importance.

Comment: I'd say "amount of paper" is fine, especially if you're talking about boxes full of blank paper, as @vir says. Or if we don't care what's on the paper, it's just a bunch of trash or old files or some such. If you were talking about documents whose content is important, then yes, I'd say "number of papers".